# Line spacing of chapter headings when using titlesec and setspace packages

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec, setspace

I have defined my own chapter heading with modified font size and spacing above and below.

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
\def \mychapter#1{\chapter*{#1}}
\begin{document}
\mychapter{Some Very Long Chapter Heading That Will Span Across Two Or More Lines}
\end{document}
```

Now I am trying to decrease line spacing (baselineskip) for this chapter heading. So I thought `setspace` package and `setstretch` command will do the trick.

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}
\def \mychapter#1{\chapter*{\setstretch{0.1}#1}}
\begin{document}
\mychapter{Some Very Long Chapter Heading That Will Span Across Two Or More Lines}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, `\setstretch{0.1}` seems to have no effect on line spacing. When used on its own, without `titlesec` package and its commands

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\def \mychapter#1{\chapter*{\setstretch{0.1}\LARGE#1}}
\begin{document}
\mychapter{Some Very Long Chapter Heading That Will Span Across Two Or More Lines}
\end{document}
```

it works as expected, but there seems to be some package conflict between `titlesec` and `setspace`.

How can I keep my `titlesec` definition of this chapter heading, but at the same time change (decrease/inrease) its line spacing?

Comment: `\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\setstretch{0.1}}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\LARGE}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the specification in the first mandatory argument (as a personal note, I consider the spacing of your definition a little bit awkward):

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]  
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\setstretch{0.1}}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Some Very Long Chapter Heading That Will Span Across Two Or More Lines}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since, according to comments, no numbering will be used, the following definition would seem the proper way to go (no need for an additional command); I also incorporated [**barbara beeton**'s suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214979/line-spacing-of-chapter-headings-when-using-titlesec-and-setspace-packages/214982#comment504543_214982) about suppressing hypheneation in the titles:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]  
  {\normalfont\filright\bfseries\setstretch{0.1}}
  {}{0pt}{\LARGE}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Some Very Long Chapter Heading That Will Span Across Two Or More Lines}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know this spacing is awful. 1) I always use starred version of chapter, so I never have auto-generated number, 2) I used such small spacing just to make sure I see an effect when it finally works. I just wanted to see change, getting to right value was left for later.

Comment: oh, please suppress automatic hyphenation (and discourage line breaks at existing hyphens unless really necessary).  you've already got semi-ragged right (spaces in second line are wider than those in the last line); "full" ragged would look nicer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I knew you were going to suggest this :) I've incorporated your suggestion (and some other improvements) to my updated answer.

Comment: @Rafal Since you're always going to suppress the string "Chapter #" from titles, then a different modification of your definition might be better, so you don't have to use a user defined command. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: This is simply awful; no document should have something so horrible!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for suggestion, but I am using user defined command for few other things as well (which were not relevant for this question) including customizing table of contents entries and page headers and footers. So it is not a problem for me to use that custom command.

Comment: @egreg I completely agree. This example was used to find solution, not to use same values in final document. See my first comment.